# Using an environment variable set to a path value: the system cannot find the path specified for %OPENCV_DIR%

Tags: windows, command-line, environment-variables

I'm trying to set an environment variable to point to the directory into which I have extracted the latest version of OpenCV, following the instructions in OpenCV's [Installation in Windows](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_install/windows_install.html) tutorial.

Here's my elevated command line listing.

```
C:\>cd C:\OpenCV2.4.6\build\x64\vc11

C:\OpenCV2.4.6\build\x64\vc11>cd ../../../..

C:\>setx -m OPENCV_DIR C:\OpenCV2.4.6\build\x64\vc11

SUCCESS: Specified value was saved.

C:\>cd %OPENCV_DIR%
The system cannot find the path specified.

C:\>echo %OPENCV_DIR%
%OPENCV_DIR%
```

1. Firstly I change directory to `C:\OpenCV2.4.6\build\x64\vc11` to ensure that it exists.
2. After that is successful I change directory back to the root of the C drive.
3. Then I use `setx` to make `OPENCV_DIR` a system wide environment variable with value the `C:\OpenCV2.4.6\build\x64\vc11` path I verified in step 1.
4. Noting the success of `setx` in the previous step I now change directory using the new environment variable. But it fails with the message `The system cannot find the path specified.`
5. If I try to `echo` the value of the `OPENCV_DIR` environment variable it appears not to be set.

Looking in the control panel the OPENCV_DIR environment variable looks correctly set:

[image: OPENCV_DIR environment variable in the control panel screenshot]

What's wrong? Why is the variable not working? Am I evoking it incorrectly when I use it to change directory or echo its value?

Comment: <clutchingatstraws>I'm going to try restarting the PC - I haven't tried that.</clutchingatstraws>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Next time just try to close and reopen the process (hehe what a cliche...)

The reason is that once a process is launched, all the variables are being written to its own address space.

If you are changing the User \ System variables - the open cmd.exe (for example) won't get the new values, but a new cmd.exe process will...

gl,

Refael

Comment: Works every time!

Answer (score 0):

Restarting the PC fixed the problem!

```
C:\windows\system32>cd %OPENCV_DIR%
C:\OpenCV2.4.6\build\x64\vc11>echo %OPENCV_DIR%
C:\OpenCV2.4.6\build\x64\vc11
```